# Playstation video game where you play Blood Angels

Tags: story-identification, video-games, warhammer-40k

I saw this back when movie/video game rentals were still a thing. I think this was a first person shooter but never played it so I can't be sure- according to the game's description a massive spacecraft (a space hulk is how it's described) is being steered toward an Imperial world by genestealers and the player, as a Blood Angel Space Marine (or part of a squad of Blood Angels) boards the hulk to divert it from crashing onto said Imperial planet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Space Hulk: Vengeance of the Blood Angels](https://www.giantbomb.com/space-hulk-vengeance-of-the-blood-angels/3030-1518/)*?

[image: From cover of Vengeance of the Blood Angels] (click to enlarge)

> The second video game adaptation of the Space Hulk board game (after the 1993 PC game Space Hulk), Vengeance of the Blood Angels puts players in control of a Space Marine Terminator, belonging to the honorable Blood Angels chapter, in the 41st millennium. Like the previous adaptation, this game combines first-person shooter gameplay (with a calsutrophobic [sic] grid-based system similar to late-'80s first-person RPGs) with real-time tactical elements.
>
> Along with numerous training "historical" missions (including those based on the original board game and the 1993 PC game), the game features a main campaign where players start off as a lowly recruit in a squad sent to prevent a runaway "space hulk" (infested with Tyranid Genestealers) from crashing into the planet Delvar III. The game starts off with the player taking basic orders from their superiors, and eventually the deaths of the commanding officers result in rapid field promotions that place the player character in control of the entire squad.
>
> It was later ported by Krisalis to the Sony PlayStation and Sega Saturn on August 1996 and to the PC on September 1996. The PS1 version supports local split-screen multiplayer (for up to two players) while the PC version supports LAN multiplayer (for up to 10 players).

### PS Gameplay

Found with a search for `video game "blood angel" "first person"`

Comment: That game was awesome.